# Anaconda - Spyder 3.3.6 - Python 2.7 - no module named matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to use matplotlib on spyder 3.3.6 but I'm having trouble importing it in the first place, is there some way to install matplotlib beforehand? I don't have a very specific question, I guess I'm just requesting someone to help me with this. I'm pretty new to using python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and it returns " ImportError: No module named matplotlib.pyplot "

when I run

```
pip install matplotlib
```

I get

```
    pip install matplotlib
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What happens after you run ‘pip install matplotlib’ ?

Comment: I edited the post to show that

Comment: If you're using Anaconda, you need to open the Anaconda prompt and run there `conda install matplotlib` (never use pip to install a package that can be installed with conda).